# How to design a high pass filter given a stopband and cutoff frequency?

Tags: circuit-design, transfer-function, bode-plot, high-pass-filter, cutoff-frequency

I have fs = 132 Hz and fc = 770 Hz

I want to design a first order high pass filter that increases gain at a rate of 20dB per decade from 132 Hz until 770 Hz.

Before 132 Hz the filter must stay around -17dB.

How do I select components to design this filter?

I am aware of the equation to select RC values for some cutoff frequency, but am not sure how to account for the stopband frequency.

Edit 1.

Below is a picture of what I have been able to achieve so far.

[image]

Next is a picture of what I need the circuit to do.

[image]

Comment: `How do I select components to design this filter?` With equations :) Your stopband frequency is defined as your frequency right before your magnitude is above zero.

Comment: @KingDuken So if I selected a first order highpass Butterworth filter, then finding a transfer function with analysis should let me substitute my stopband frequency with desired gain, and my cutoff frequency with desired gain, to then solve these simultaneous equations for R and C?

Comment: @Numpy You need to know the passband gain (often assumed to be \$0\:\text{dB}\$ if not stated.) This is found in some books' transfer functions as the multiplier \$K\$. If the passband gain is \$K=1\$, then you'd expect \$-20\cdot\operatorname{log}_{10}\left(\frac{770\:\text{Hz}}{132\:\text{Hz}}\right)\approx -15.32\:\text{dB}\$ at \$132\:\text{Hz}\$. Without the passband gain, I can't say for sure, but your figure of \$-17\:\text{dB}\$ suggests that a 1st order Butterworth may be fine. (A simple unloaded RC filter is a Butterworth.) Don't you know how to select R and C to fit \$\omega_0\$?

Comment: @jonk That’s correct, I haven’t found a general form to find R and C values for a transfer function anywhere, I currently have a circuit that mimics everything I need, except the stopband region. No parameter I change in the Butterworth gives me a stopband region from 0 to 132 Hz at -15 dB, and in fact no parameter I change yields even the smallest stopband region.

Comment: @Numpy I don't see a schematic and I don't see any work product. So I don't know how to help you with this. I assume you already have read that \$f_c=\frac1{2\pi\:R\:C}\$ and know the difference between a low pass and a high pass arrangement. Are you loading it down somehow? Or is it buffered? I don't know. Because you haven't said anything much at all. It would help a lot if you would write more and put more time into your question here.

Comment: I will upload a drawing of the bode plot the circuit is supposed to achieve in a moment.

Comment: @Numpy You can't get your 2nd diagram from a 1st order Butterworth high pass filter. Did someone tell you that you could? You can get your upper right corner. But not both corners shown in the 2nd diagram. Instead, the attenuation will continue its downward slope as the frequency goes still lower. So the lower left corner won't yield a flat stopband gain like that with a 1st order filter.

Comment: @Numpy Your 1st diagram, by the way, suggests the general picture of an Nst order Butterworth. Except that it's not correctly aligned with the frequency axis for the case you want. Is there a reason you can't compute the right R and C so that you get it positioned correctly? (The basic shape won't change, but you should be able to hit the high frequency corner correctly, at least.)

Comment: I can hit the corner no worries, just thought it would be easier to visualise how to go about shifting the whole thing along.

Comment: @Numpy Well, to make sure we are both on the same page, [here's a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuC67.png) of a 1st order Butterworth high pass filter with your specifications developed by [this filter site from Analog](https://www.analog.com/designtools/en/filterwizard/). You can see that the labeled stopband does NOT look like your 2nd diagram. Are you saying that you agree and that you only need to achieve what I'm showing you here in this comment?

Comment: I assumed it could be done with a first order filter because I also have a first order transfer function that should describe the same behaviour, but I’m not sure how to convert the function with zero and pole frequencies into a circuit.

Comment: @Numpy Let's see the transfer function you have. (By the way, I forgot to add the filter function to my earlier comment. Please go back and check the adjusted comment for the picture.)

Comment: I definitely need to replicate the behaviour of the more advanced bode, so I am assuming either my first order transfer function is wrong (which it shouldn’t be, as I was given the general form of it first), or having a first order transfer function doesn’t necessarily translate to having a first order filter.

Comment: The function is as follows: f(s) = (s-z) / (s-p)

Comment: @Numpy ***ALL*** first order high pass filters take the general form of \$\frac{s}{s+1}\$.

Comment: My zero frequency is 132, and the pole is 770.

Comment: @Numpy Have you considered the idea of using a low pass filter to extract the nearer DC part and then subtract it? Or, alternately, using one RC pair for high pass and paralleling that with another low-pass RC pair? (So, an RC-RC divider?)

Comment: I have definitely thought of trying something with two filters to make use of the initial passband of a low pass somehow, but have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: @Numpy I think I finally understand what you are trying to achieve. You may need to write more thoroughly in the future so save everyone's time and wasted effort. (It's courteous.) Your transfer function, plus the graphs, would have cleared up a lot. It's now late for me and I have other chores to finish before going to bed. But tomorrow, if someone else hasn't then I can may try and do some justice to it now that I follow you better than I did before. That said, I also don't know if this will work 1st order (corners might be too tightly drawn and you've admitted you aren't sure, either.)

Comment: I posted another question from the transfer function perspective, however no one was able to help. Thanks for your time, I’m certain it will be here tomorrow waiting.

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: @Numpy I guess you need to edit your original question and make it more complete and detailed. I won't be able to reply here. And I can't reply there until and unless you properly update it with all of the necessary information you've added here (and what else you can additionally include.)